# capistrano v3 deploy git repository and its submodules

Tags: capistrano, git-submodules

With capistrano v2 submodules can be includes in the deploy by using option:

```
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
```

In v3 this does not seem to work. Is this option still supported or is there a new way to reach the same goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the Capistrano source code https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L34 and https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L56 it uses `git archive` to check out the code into the release directory.

The code is reproduced here:

```rb
desc 'Clone the repo to the cache'
task clone: :'git:wrapper' do
  on roles :all do
    if test " [ -f #{repo_path}/HEAD ] "
      info t(:mirror_exists, at: repo_path)
    else
      within deploy_path do
        with git_environmental_variables do
          execute :git, :clone, '--mirror', repo_url, repo_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
desc 'Update the repo mirror to reflect the origin state'
task update: :'git:clone' do
  on roles :all do
    within repo_path do
      execute :git, :remote, :update
    end
  end
end
desc 'Copy repo to releases'
task create_release: :'git:update' do
  on roles :all do
    with git_environmental_variables do
    within repo_path do
      execute :mkdir, '-p', release_path
      execute :git, :archive, fetch(:branch), '| tar -x -C', release_path
    end
  end
 end
```

From that we can ascertain that submodules are not supported. As the commands to clone or initialize submodules are never issued, and git-archive ignores them.

The decision was made (source: Capistrano author here) not to include submodules "out of the box" as the hooks needed to build this in, if you need it are already there, and it's trivial to write an add-on task that does what you need to checkout/update submodules in a way that works for you. The Capistrano v2 submodule support often had unexpected consequences for people.

With that in mind. It might be worth to hooking into `update`, to initialize and update your submodules after the update is finished, and examining ways to augment `git-archive` do do what you need.

Comment: In other words: it's not trivial or you would have already illustrated how to do that. I believe this is a very wrong decision to use git archive for the archiving task... Also, Rake doesn't support task overriding out of the box. The only way I can see for deal with this problem is to clear that create_release task and recreate it to use another command for archiving the code with submodules :(

Comment: "Rake doesn't support task overriding out of the box." is blatantly wrong, the API certainly lends itself to extension, rather than replacement, but that's because it's a build tool. If the Cap defaults don't work for you, you are encouraged to copy the .task files out of the Gem and modify them in your app, that's why it's been built in standard formats using standard tools, so that people can do exactly that. Your submodule usecase isn't special, but it's also moderately more complex than the archive one. With modern git versions wide submodule support is much easier, but archive is simpler.

Answer (score 3):

In capistrano 3.1.x and later you can implement your own SCM strategy. There is an available gem that helps with git submodule, please see: https://github.com/i-ekho/capistrano-git-submodule-strategy.

NOTE: you may have problem with the `repo` folder if you already tried with the default git strategy. Simply go to the deploy directory on server and remove it and then run cap deploy again to fix.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out it's very difficult to hook into any of the git tasks of capistrano (because they don't exist until the stage is set). Besides, git archive does not in any way provide support for submodules, so that part has to be completely replaced.

Copy and paste is also not an option for obvious reasons.

So I wrote this simple gem that can replace the git scm. It uses a similiar approach to capistrano 2, by cloning the repo with its submodules. It is very simple and enough for our goals. I suspect there are not many different usages of submodules out there (if people try to avoid complications).

https://github.com/juanibiapina/capistrano-scm-gitsubmodules

Let me know if it helps you too.

UPDATE:

This module has been deprecated with capistrano 3.1.0. Try this instead: https://gist.github.com/stevenscg/8176735

Answer (score 2):

The new Pull Request "828" is trying to implement that again:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/pull/828

As discussed by @coffeeaddict, this [Commit](https://github.com/coffeeaddict/documentation/commit/35f9279b54620892ec187de6c3d0f2a36c053251) is a scrap of the code you will need to deploy locally until it's bundled with the capistrano itself. Please note that you need Capistrano >= 3.1.0 to use the code.

There is also another [Gist](https://gist.github.com/stevenscg/8176735) that suggest to fix some issues of the strategy above.