# Deploying a git submodule with Capistrano 3

Tags: git, deployment, capistrano, git-submodules, capistrano3

My project repo includes Wordpress as a git submodule.  When deploying via Capistrano 3, the submodule directory is barren.

```
project
--wordpress
--images
```

I am using git and `:deploy_via, :remote_cache`

How can I tell Capistrano to also deploy the submodule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a great script from corny that overrides the git task in Capistrano.

Place this script in `lib/capistrano/tasks/git.cap` and use `cap stage deploy` as normal.

https://gist.github.com/corny/7459729

```
# Save this file as lib/capistrano/tasks/git.cap

namespace :git do
  desc 'Copy repo to releases'
  task create_release: :'git:update' do
    on roles(:all) do
      with fetch(:git_environmental_variables) do
        within repo_path do
          execute :git, :clone, '-b', fetch(:branch), '--recursive', '.', release_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting an error when creating the release symlink.

Comment: Be sure your repo directories on your server are emptied before trying for the first time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I SSH into my server and check the doc root there is no git repo created by Capistrano.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the same thing we are talking about, but on capistrano v3, there is a task that removes the .git directory after deploy to save disk space. I believe that it's something that you can override and disable.

Comment: A best place for the script is to add it to the `deploy.rb`

Comment: I had to add it directly to deploy.rb as many of the other posters have recommended and mentioned here also https://gist.github.com/corny/7459729

Answer (score 4):

Probably duplicated with [capistrano v3 deploy git repository and its submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403138/capistrano-v3-deploy-git-repository-and-its-submodules).

In capistrano 3.1.x and later you can implement your own SCM strategy. There is an available gem that helps with git submodule, please see: https://github.com/i-ekho/capistrano-git-submodule-strategy.

NOTE: you may have problem with the `repo` folder if you already tried with the default git strategy. Simply go to the deploy directory and remove it and then run cap deploy again to fix it.