# Capistrano Submodule Init and Update Task

Tags: wordpress, git, capistrano, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano (as part of [Bedrock](https://github.com/roots/bedrock)) to deploy Wordpress.

I'm also using Composer to manage php dependencies and my WordPress plugins, and I have my theme managed by git as a submodule.

I've got everything setup and I've successfully deployed WordPress to my remote server.

The problem is I'm managing my custom theme with git submodules. I can't find a way to init and update the submodule during the default deployment, or as a separate task. I'd prefer to have it as a separate task as I don't change the underlining project files too frequently.

1. I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbbx6spp/154482) that creates a task to do the same but its using an older version of Capistrano.
2. I tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819265/deploying-a-git-submodule-with-capistrano-3) but it fails when trying to create the release symlinks.
3. I tried enabling submodules with `set :git_enable_submodules, 1` in my `deploy.rb` file but that seems to be missing from Capistrano V3.x.
4. I [found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403138/capistrano-v3-deploy-git-repository-and-its-submodules) where the author of Capistrano explains why submodule support was removed and another commenter posted [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bhaberer/8835805), which is giving me this error `Tasks: TOP => git:create_release => git:update => git:clone`.

What are other people doing to enable simple deployments with Capistrano that include git submodules?

Comment: Welp it looks like the simplest solution by far is to just remove the submodule and commit the theme to my project so it's all deployed by Capistrano. :(

Comment: Looks like my submodule was improperly added to my super-project. When I examines the super-project's .git/config it was apparent that the submodule was not mapped. Also the super-project contained no .gitmodules files. This may have caused my issues but I decided to remove the submodule all together and merge it into the super-project to avoid any more problems with capistrano.

Answer (score 1):

i also use git submodule in capistrano 2 i used:

`set :git_enable_submodules, 1`

worked prefctly.

when i moved into Capistrano 3.x i started to use:

```
namespace :git do
  desc 'Copy repo to releases'
  task create_release: :'git:update' do
    on roles(:all) do
      with fetch(:git_environmental_variables) do
        within repo_path do
          execute :git, :clone, '-b', fetch(:branch), '--recursive', '.', release_path
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

also working like a charm.

see more details here:

https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L34
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake#L56

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that is the same solution I tried from #2 above.